# I want that frame get every second. (opencv)

Tags: opencv

I expect result that is when this code is excuted, I gain one frame every second.

but maybe cap buffer is existed, so I don't gain frame cut off.

this frame is successive.

I want to gain one frame and  After 1 second, to gain frame(After 1 second frame )

What is the problem?

```
VideoCapture cap(0) ;
while(1){
    cap >> frame ;
    sleep(1) ;
    imshow("test", frame) ;
    if(waitKey(30)>=0) break ;
}
```

Comment: I use raspberry pi3 and picam

Comment: probably there is such a buffer and you can't change it yourself: http://answers.opencv.org/question/90583/videocapture-buffer/

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky because the buffer doesn't allow you to skip frames using a waitKey...this means that your current code will wait for as long as you specify, then show the **immediately next frame**, not the one after the delay.

However, if you wish to show the frames that come only at t={1sec, 2sec...}, then you can generate a timer yourself, using the getTickCount() and getTickFrequency() functions, as shown:

```
VideoCapture cap(0) ;
int t=getTickCount()/getTickFrequency();//at the starting of loop
while(1){
    cap >> frame ;
    //sleep(1);
    if(getTickCount()/getTickFrequency()-t>=1000){//in milliseconds
    //here getTickCount() is constantly updated, but t is fixed till you reset it
          imshow("test", frame) ;
          t=getTickCount()/getTickFrequency();//reset the difference back to 0
    }
    if(waitKey(30)>=0) 
    break ;
}
```